# What does the exception Uncaught Error: Invalid record id returned for... means?

Tags: debugging, extjs

We are using ExtJS 6.0.0 GPL

The situation includes a Grid which when a row is selected and the edit button is clicked a form is created.
The form has its fields bind to a dynamic view model.
This view model has a link to the model that corresponds to the row.

Not sure if the above helps but we really cannot any make sense of the below exception.

> Uncaught Error: Invalid record id returned for 5@UserExt.Error @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:2312Ext.apply.raise @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:2371Ext.raise @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:2450options.recordCreator @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:80876Ext.define.extractRecord @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:82934Ext.define.extractData @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:82890Ext.Base.Base.addMembers.callParent @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:11714Ext.define.extractData @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:86691Ext.define.readRecords @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:82834Ext.Base.Base.addMembers.callParent @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:11714Ext.define.readRecords @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:86634Ext.define.read @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:82749Ext.define.processResponse @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:85771(anonymous function) @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:86367Ext.apply.callback @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:8174Ext.define.onComplete @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:24691Ext.define.onStateChange @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:24631(anonymous function) @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1445528508045:6404

The result is that the form appears but the fields are not filled with the data and if a user tries one more then the whole app crashes.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Can you post the model? Are you using an custom identifier or config a 'special' id field on the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha ExtJS magic created this strange error.

Actually in the background there was a GET request to retrieve a specific model from the server.

#### Strange behavior costs time

This was an unexpected behavior of extjs framework because the models were already retrieved and saved in memory.
There was no source code of ours asking or implying any connection with the server at this point.

We guess that this is the default behavior in order to refresh the data from the server just in case some other user has changed the data in the meantime but still it came as a surprise.

This kind of "magic" is rarely good for any development team.

Anyways after implementing `/user/list?id=XXX` it worked fine.
*Note we are using a proxy ajax*

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old but I would like to say that this behaviour is the result of not having the store in the session.

Go to the viewmodel and set the configuration for the store that is binded to the grid as session: true and that's all.

Otherwise you will have to implement a single model response on your server when the model proxy sends a record id to it.

Another interesting behaviour is, when you try to edit the first row of your grid there is a round trip to the server, your server answers with all rows and as the rows returned by the server have the same order, the first row is the same you are trying to edit so the framework succeed to parse the data and will not bark with errors.